# Can you always win last man standing?

Tags: max-payne-3

I seem to frequently die in the 'last man standing' showdown because:

- Out of ammo.
- Target is obstructed by cover.
- Max is in an awkward position e.g.doing a flip, and can't get a target in time.

Can you actually do anything in these situations to not die?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can you actually do anything in **these situations** to not die?

No.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Why downvotes? The answer is short but still correct. There are sometimes situations in which you just can't win a last man standing due to the situations mentioned in the question.

Comment: What's there to elaborate? There's some situations where you simply can't win last man standing, period. 3 of them are being mentioned in the original post. Either one or a combination of 2 or all 3 will make it impossible to win last man standing.

Comment: And that's fine, but can you explain why the answer is no? Why is there nothing one can do in these situations? However, if the question is so trivial as to not be worth a full response, you should be flagging it so it can be closed, not leaving one-word answers.

Comment: @MarkTrapp because you can't shoot the target, duh.

Comment: The OP asked a question. I answered correctly. Case closed. If you want a 3 paged essay as to WHY, you're SOL. And no, I won't flag anything. The question asker deserved an answer, and that's that. Maybe somebody will delve deep into the game mechanics and explain why in these situations the answer is NO. I won't. I'm not obliged to.

Comment: well, you COULD power off your console or PC immediately. That's one way out. :)